# Incorrect markup for Xpage

Tags: xpages

I notice in our application the markup of xpages has been dramatically altered e.g.:

```
<xp_1:djButton label="Remove document"
    id="djButton3">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onClick"
        submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp_1:this.action>
```

This across the application. We have no idea what the cause is. The application has been untouched for at least a year.

The pages get rendered properly but we get incidents reported that some actions are not working.

DDE is not complaining, propably due to the xmlns:xp_1="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex definition.

Is there any other odd behaviour we could expect?

Comment: Cannot confirm here, working with Dom Designer V 10.0.1 FP1. Do you have an idea what could have caused the change of namespace? Like rolling out a new designer version?

Comment: (was to slow to complete my comment, this continues from above): 
Basically you're using an element from the extlib palette (djbutton); adding this should create a new namespace with prefix "xe" in your xpage's root node. But of course the prefix can be renamed to anything, like xp_1 instead. The action however should still be linked to prefix "xp" like the eventHandler, not to "xe" or "xp_1" in your case, so this is the strange part